# linq query returns too many results

Tags: c#, .net, linq

EDIT: This question is now solved

I am currently trying to do a simple selection of multiple columns from various tables using LINQ, which I am very new to. Basically I am combining results from multiple tables using inner joins in order to give some of that information to my model, which I then pas to a view. The query only ever returns the first result (which is a correct result) and returns it more times than it appears, while never showing any of the other results. That is, it repeats the first result multiple times while never displaying any other results.

So if the output was supposed to say something like (this is just an example)

```
Name     Task Name   Status
Derp    Do the Dishes   ACTIVE
John    Example Task    COMPLETE
Jesus   Walk on Water   IMPOSSIBLE
```

it would instead say

```
Name     Task Name   Status
Derp    Do the Dishes   ACTIVE
Derp    Do the Dishes   ACTIVE
Derp    Do the Dishes   ACTIVE
Derp    Do the Dishes   ACTIVE
Derp    Do the Dishes   ACTIVE
Derp    Do the Dishes   ACTIVE
Derp    Do the Dishes   ACTIVE
Derp    Do the Dishes   ACTIVE
Derp    Do the Dishes   ACTIVE
```

I assume there is something wrong with my LINQ syntax.

Here is the relevant part of my controller:

```
var TaskInstanceList = taskInstanceService.SelectAll();
        var Person = personService.SelectAll();
        var Task = taskService.SelectAll();
        var Status = statusService.SelectAll();

        var NewModel = new TaskLogModelContainer();
        NewModel.Tasks = new List<TaskLogModel>();

        var results = from ti in TaskInstanceList
                      join p in Person on ti.personID equals p.personID
                      join t in Task on ti.taskID equals t.taskID
                      join s in Status on ti.task_statusID equals s.statusID
                      select new { Person = p, Task = t, Status = s, Instance = ti };

        foreach (var result in results)
        {
            var obj = new TaskLogModel();
            obj.ID = result.Instance.person_taskID;
            obj.FirstName = result.Person.FirstName;
            obj.LastName = result.Person.LastName;
            obj.Description = result.Task.Description;
            obj.TaskName = result.Task.Name;
            obj.Value = result.Task.Value;
            obj.Status = result.Status.Status;
            obj.Notes = result.Status.Notes;

            NewModel.Tasks.Add(obj);
        }

        return View(NewModel);
```

and here is my view

```
@model MyProj.Models.TaskLogModelContainer

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "index";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Task Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Status
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model.Tasks)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>@item.FirstName @item.LastName</td>
        <td>@item.TaskName</td>
        <td>@item.Status</td>
    </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: I just tested your code with fake data and it works fine and normally. here it is : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/67454234/Program.cs

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is.... Is your query returning one row where you expect multiple rows?

Comment: I will edit the original post to clarify the problem

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify, if your Linq statement returns too much results or if the amount of data in the output does not correspond to the query.

If your Linq statement returns too much results you may reduce your query to a single join.
So start with:

```
  var results = from ti in TaskInstanceList
  join p in Person on ti.personID equals p.personID
```

then

```
  var results = from ti in TaskInstanceList
  join t in Task on ti.taskID equals t.taskID
```

Remark: This text should by a comment - my reputation does not allow to write one

Comment: I only get the result for the first row. The actual row data is correct. The row is repeated about 7 or 8 times.

Comment: Glad to hear the problem is solved. Just a consideration: Instead of using  "select new { Person = p, Task = t, Status = s, Instance = ti };" you may directly instantiate your TaskLogModel object "select new TaskLogModel { FirstName = p.FirstName, ... }

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED.

One of my SelectAll statements was bugged. Which is just plain weird, because I have tested them all thorouhly and was using it an hour ago with no problems. Maybe I accidentally ctrl-z'd something or bumped a key.

Comment: Had it got to do with `TaskInstanceList`? I guess, that could be a culprit.